# Testing unconfirmed addresses in PayPal Sandbox

Tags: paypal, paypal-sandbox

I'm working on an integration between a shopping cart and PayPal. I'm using the SOAP API and Express Checkout. What I want to test is the behavior of the system when the shipping address of the buyer is [unconfirmed](https://www.paypal.com/cgi-bin/?cmd=p/pop/confirmed_address_checkout-outside). I've created a sandbox account which is not "Bank Verified Account" and its wallet is empty.

Anyway the address status is always "Confirmed" as seen in the snippet below:

```
<GetExpressCheckoutDetailsResponseDetails xmlns="urn:ebay:apis:eBLBaseComponents" xsi:type="ebl:GetExpressCheckoutDetailsResponseDetailsType">
    ...
    <Token xsi:type="ebl:ExpressCheckoutTokenType">EC-17S48212F9774382J</Token>
    ...
    <PayerInfo xsi:type="ebl:PayerInfoType">
        ...
        <PayerStatus xsi:type="ebl:PayPalUserStatusCodeType">unverified</PayerStatus>
        <PayerCountry xsi:type="ebl:CountryCodeType">DE</PayerCountry>
        <Address xsi:type="ebl:AddressType">
            <Name xsi:type="xs:string">...</Name>
            <Street1 xsi:type="xs:string">...</Street1>
            <Street2 xsi:type="xs:string"/>
            <CityName xsi:type="xs:string">...</CityName>
            <StateOrProvince xsi:type="xs:string"/>
            <Country xsi:type="ebl:CountryCodeType">DE</Country>
            <CountryName>Germany</CountryName>
            <PostalCode xsi:type="xs:string">11111</PostalCode>
            <AddressOwner xsi:type="ebl:AddressOwnerCodeType">PayPal</AddressOwner>
            <AddressStatus xsi:type="ebl:AddressStatusCodeType">Confirmed</AddressStatus>
        </Address>
    </PayerInfo>
</GetExpressCheckoutDetailsResponseDetails>
```

How can I emulate unconfirmed addresses?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately, for sandbox environment address will be confirmed. Only way is to test issuing live.